# Laravel uploading files asynchronously

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, file-upload, laravel-queue

I'm fairly familiar with Laravel Queues and running asynchronous logic in Laravel by scheduling jobs.

The website I am building needs to handle large video files, so I need these uploads to be async, users now are waiting 5 to 10 minutes for their file to upload.

Is this possible? How would this be implemented into a Laravel Queue? What gets sent to the server in the request?

I can't find anything on Google tackling this issue, so I'm just looking for some general guidance.

The ideal would be for the user to choose their file, click upload, then a job is scheduled to upload the file and notify the user by email when complete.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to queue something that requires the user-server connection to remain alive for the duration. You can't really queue that. What you could do is to just throw the upload in a temporary location and add the processing task of the file to a queue. The file itself must be in the server storage for this to work though. Keep in mind that the file uploads are asynchronous in the sense that many users can upload files concurrently. There's no need for a user to wait on other uploads

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah I understand. The best method would be to do the upload with JavaScript and show the user a progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For files to upload, the **page that initiated the upload must remain open for the duration of the upload**. This makes sense in itself because otherwise if a user chooses to close the page with the upload in progress, you could essentially *"steal"* the uploading file regardless of the user's action.

The only practical approach here is to allow the user to select files and upload them using an XHR request, something along the lines of:

```
var payload = new FormData();
payload.append('file', document.getElementById('fileInput'));

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);

xhr.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    // Do stuff when upload is complete
});

xhr.send(payload);
```

Uploading the files asynchronously, allows the user to do other action within the same page while waiting for the upload to finish (e.g. fill in additional data required with the upload).

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the approach I will take, and show the user a progress bar.